# Django forms input restriction

Tags: javascript, django, forms, input

```
  tr_id = forms.CharField(required=False, max_length=20,
    widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        'class':'filter filter_tr_id',
        'placeholder':'TR ID'
    })
)
```

I would like to restrict this Django input for only numbers and underscore. I've already got a js function which does the job. how I can add onkeyup feature in the input ?

```
function number_only(id_tr_id) {
var regex = /[^0-9\._]/g; 
id_tr_id.value = id_tr_id.value.replace(regex,"");

}
```

Is there any other way I can restrict the input for numbers and underscore only?

Answer (score 0):

yes, You can add a pattern attribute in input field

```js
tr_id = forms.CharField(required=False, max_length=20,
    widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        'class':'filter filter_tr_id',
        'placeholder':'TR ID',
        'pattern':'[0-9_]'
    })
)
```

Comment: html input field support a pattern attrs which add a restriction to input field. may be regex can be wrong but this method will krega.https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp

Comment: Thanks @SHIVAM JINDAL. with this pattern I can still add the string as well. how can I put an alert on the input, if it does meet with the pattern ?

Comment: when you submit form and input does not meet the regex it will show error.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_pattern  try to modify regex in the example and submit